# Github: added to org and have rights but unable to push

Tags: git, github

I was added to my work org's github, to which it's an organization assigned github username.  I was added to that repo and cloned it locally.  I made a change and went to push and see `fatal: Could not read from the remote repository Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repo exists`.
I checked the ssh pub key I added to my github org profile and it's the same as my computer's.

The only other thing I changed, which I would suspect would not effect this, was I edited `git.config --global user.name` and  `git.config --global user.email` to put in my "Phillip C" for my name and "phillipC@myOrg.com" for email.

The ssh key has:

```
ssh-rsa [My whole long key]phillipC@Phillips-Macbook-Pro.local
```

Could it be because the username/email was expecting `phillipC@Phillips-Macbook-Pro.local` from the ssh pub key?

Comment: The last part of an SSH key is a comment and can be anything. It's not used for authentication. `user.name`/`user.email` also aren't used for authentication, only for commit creation.

Comment: thanks @phd .  So how does git know who i am?  iSo would it be something on the org's side that is restricting me then?

Comment: Not enough info. Verify `git remote -v` — is it the correct repo? Does it use SSH protocol — either `git@github.com:user/repo` or `ssh://git@github.com/user/repo`? Try `ssh -Tv git@github.com` — does it recognize you?

Comment: it's the correct repo..it uses `git@github.com:user/repo`.  I just tried `ssh -Tv git@github.com` and it was a long debug output, which at the end says `The authenticity of host git@github.com can't be established.  RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:***********. Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bssh%5D+The+authenticity+of+host+can%27t+be+established

Comment: "The authenticity of host git@github.com can't be established.  RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:***********. Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])" That would a "yes", eh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your key (*ahem*) question is actually in a comment:

> So how does git know who i am?

The answer is: *Git* **does not know or care**.  Git does no authentication at all.  Git makes commits (`git commit`), extracts commits (`git checkout`), and does other things purely locally, on your computer.  For this, it does not *need* authentication.  Your computer does whatever authentication your computer does, and that's all Git cares about.

Git also, however, transfers commits to another Git (`git fetch` or `git push`).  This involves calling up some other Git, typically over the Internet-phone.  This *does* need authentication.

*Git doesn't do it.*

Git relies on external software—software that establishes the connection *to* the other Git, so that your Git can talk to their Git—to do *all* the authentication.  Git continues not to know or care who you are.  It will, under various circumstances and/or using various helpers, deliver some claim(s) from you about who you are to whatever software is going to vet those claims.  This is where things start getting complicated.  Fortunately you're using `ssh` here.  Ssh authentication is extremely complex (and flexible) but ssh needs no help from Git.  You just plug in a URL, such as:

```
ssh://git@github.com/path/to/repo.git
```

or:

```
git@github.com:path/to/repo.git
```

(these two strings mean exactly the same thing to Git; Git takes the `ssh://` part as meaning "use ssh", and the `git@github.com:` part as meaning "use ssh", and then passes the `git@github.com` part *to* ssh).

[The reason phd suggests using `ssh -Tv git@github.com`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67097894/github-added-to-org-and-have-rights-but-unable-to-push#comment118603336_67097894) is that this takes Git entirely out of the equation.  You can now see whether ssh is able to call up `git@github.com` and if so, whether whoever answers the "phone" there believes that you are *you*.  You now need only deal with ssh itself.

What you need to know here is that when ssh sees `git@github.com`, your ssh:

- turns `github.com` into an Internet address (IPv4 or IPv6);
- uses your OS's networking to contact someone there on the standard ssh port (TCP port 22);
- verifies that as far as you / your system can tell, you're talking to the same system you were talking to last time—or if this can't be discovered, gives you that `authenticity of host ... can't be established` message, and lets you decide whether to risk talking to them; and
- assuming you allow it to proceed (or that you did before and so it seems safe to talk to the same computer again), sends some credential information to them, saying *I would like to log in as user `git`*.

This last part is correct!  You don't have an actual *login account* on GitHub.  You log in as the pseudo-user named `git`.  So do I, and so does everyone else who uses GitHub (well, everyone except the internal administrators and such).

In order to log in as user `git`, they demand that you send them a key, and they send you a key.  The key you send them is derived from the ones you generated above.  (These—the ones you generated, that has that comment at the end, are actually a pair, a *public key* and a *private key*.)

The trick that GitHub use here is that they know who you are *by* the *key that you give to them*.  All of these key exchanges and cryptographic tricks result in them—GitHub—getting, from you, a secret that you gave to them earlier.  Only you know that secret (presumably) so if they see *that particular secret*, this must be *you*.  If they see *my* secret, they know that some connection trying to "log in" as `git` is from *me*.

Once GitHub figure out who you are—from this information—they then allow this `git@github.com` connection to proceed, or not, to talk to a Git program that accesses the repository at the path you supply, based on whether the "you" that they figured out here is *supposed* to be able to access that repository.

The `ssh -Tv` trick is a simple way to have them tell you who they have figured you out to be.  The user `git@github.com` has only limited access on GitHub: it can only run Git commands.  Successfully authenticating to log in, but asking for a shell instead of to run Git transfers, gets a friendly "error message" of the form:

```
Hi _____! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub
does not provide shell access.
```

(except that the blank is filled in) and then immediately quits.

#### This way you can tell *who they think you are*

The reason we need this is that if you have multiple accounts and different ways to access GitHub—which often occurs in corporate environments, for instance—you may have *multiple keys that would give you access* to various repositories.  Some key will identify you as "you at home" for instance.  You would use these for your personal repositories.  Other keys might identify you as "you at job X" and "you at job Y" and these would authenticate access to job-X and job-Y repositories respectively.

If you only have one key, all this stuff simplifies away: you either successfully authenticate as yourself, or you don't authenticate at all.  The test is still useful.  If you have more than one key, this test is even more useful because now you can see *which* key—or more precisely, which key that *worked*—you had your ssh send *first*.

If you have a very large number of keys, you'll need to learn more about ssh to learn how to control *which keys get offered*.  If your ssh comes along with a ring of a million keys and just keeps trying them randomly, they are probably going to get suspicious and kill your connection.  You'll want to have your ssh *pre-select* the *right* key.  This is also useful when you have two or three keys that will work, since the *first* (correct) key is the one that causes GitHub to believe you are who you claim to be, via that key.